# Emulator not working in windows10 machine

Tags: android, android-emulator

emulator: WARNING: Another emualtor is still running, wait for a sec... emulator: WARNING: Another emualtor is still running, wait for a sec... emulator: WARNING: Another emualtor is still running, wait for a sec... emulator: ERROR: Another emulator instance is running. Please close it or run all emulators with -read-only flag.

I have tried restarting the studio, system, lock file removal nothing worked. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you installed HAXM installer in your Windows10? It is required to run an emulator in Windows10.

Comment: yes I have checked HAXM is there at that time itself and everything is there.